# onCreateOptionsMenu in fragment not showing for API <= 16

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to display an options menu in a certain fragment in my android application.

In my fragment i have overridden the following methods:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overview_activity_menu, menu);
}
```

The methods are triggered when a user presses the **physical options-button** of an android device (I am not using an **actionbar**).

The menu is specified like this.

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_as_dish"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_add_as_dish" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_copy_to_other_day"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/copy_to_other_day" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_to_shoppinglist"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/add_to_shoppinglist" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_remove"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/remove_selected" />
</menu>`

Now, this code works well on a **Samsung Galaxy S4 API** level 18 (I´ve tested using [**Genymotion**](http://www.genymotion.com)) and the menu is displayed exactly like I want it.

However, when I run this code on my own devices, the menu just won't show. 
I have used breakpoints to verify that the methods are actually called, but there is no menu visible.

My own devices run on API <= 16, and I am sensing that this has something to do with why the menus are not displayed.

How can I make the menu appear on API >= 14 devices?

P.S. API 14 is the min. SDK version that I need to support.

Comment: "The methods are triggered when a user presses the physical options-button of an android device" -- many Android devices do not have a "physical options-button", and no devices shipping with Android 4.4+ will have a "physical options-button". You need to rewrite your UI to either include the action bar or create your own menu system integrated into your UI (like games do). See http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/12/09/menu-key-dead-again.html for more.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will rethink my implementation. However, this does not change the fact that the menus are not show at all. My devices all have physical menu buttons.

Comment: Either change `ifRoom` to `never`, or add `android:icon` attributes.